# How to prefetch for individual object? (AttributeError: object has no attribute 'select_related')

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

How do I prefetch for a single object?

I.e. select_related for a ForeignKey for one object:

```
# models.py

class Bar(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField()

class Foo(models.Model):
  bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
```

```
b1 = Bar.objects.create(title="Bar")
f1 = Foo.objects.create(bar=b1)
Foo.objects.all().first().select_related("bar")
# AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'select_related'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select_related` is used on querysets, and using it on the result of `first()` will have you working on a single instance, causing the error.

So you'll have to do `select_related` first before calling `first()`:

```
Foo.objects.select_related("bar").first()
```

Comment: What about if I have the object directly? E.g. in my original post, I know my object is `f1`. `f1.select_related("bar")` gives the same error while putting that single object into a queryset (e.g. `Foo.objects.select_related("bar").filter(id=f1.id)`) creates additional queries and seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: Shouldn't create additional queries, just a single query with more complex SQL. (prefetch_related does generate an extra query). If you install django-debug-toolbar you can easily see the exact SQL that is generated.

Comment: At the time when you have `f1`, you have already executed the sql to get that single object. So selecting bar after getting that single object will always leave you with another query to get the related `bar`. So you should select the related `bar` beforehand always if you know you will need it.

Comment: Thanks @BrianDestura ... that's what I thought might have been happening. In my scenario, I happen to be using a third-party's method to get the initial object that I want to prefetch off of (e.g. `foo.get_custom_obj()`) so I guess it makes sense why prefetching won't work - I'd have to overwrite the custom method to implement the prefetch when that initial object is initially selected.

Comment: yep sounds like i the override is needed in this case